# Make union of table appear in order they are applied

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written a SQL Server query which returns the union of few select statements. The query returns the data as I expect.

But one unexpected thing it is doing is that it is sorting the data in alphabetical order. However, what I want is that data of first table should appear on top and data of second table should appear second and so on.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
select employeename from employeetable where employeename like 'vik%'
union
select employeename from employeetable where employeename like '% vik%'
union
select employeename from EmployeeTable where employeename like '%vik%' and
                                             employeename not like 'vik%' and
                                             employeename not like '% vik%'
```

Comment: Add 1 to first select, 2 to second etc.

Comment: @jarlh: could you please share the example

Comment: `select 1 as ord, employeename from employeetable ... order by ord`.

Comment: Simple rule - if you don't have an `ORDER BY` (and it has to be on the outermost query, rather than part of a subquery) then the system is free to return results in whatever manner is most convenient.

Comment: To me, it seems that UNION ALL would produce the desired effect.

Comment: I hope that table isn't too big. Those leading wildcards will prevent any efficient index usage.

Comment: @Henrique - not without an `ORDER BY`. There is **no** guarantee on the order of results returned from a `UNION (ALL)`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you show me a practical example where resultsets are not concatenated in specified order? It os not asked to order by arbitrary column, just that resultsets are concatenated in a given order (each resultset can me ordered by its own execution plan).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without `union`:

```
select employeename
from employeetable
where employeename like '%vik%'
order by (case when employeename like 'vik%' then 1
               when employeename like '% vik%' then 2
               else 3
          end);
```

If you can can duplicate `employeename`s in `employeetable`, then you can use `group by` to remove duplicates:

```
select employeename
from employeetable
where employeename like '%vik%'
group by employeename
order by (case when employeename like 'vik%' then 1
               when employeename like '% vik%' then 2
               else 3
          end);
```

Comment: Do `SELECT DISTINCT` to return same as `UNION`.

Comment: @jarlh . . . It is unlikely that there are duplicate names in the table -- given that the separate queries *can* return duplicates.  If there are, then `select distinct` would be appropriate.

Comment: If i do `SELECT DISTINCT`, then query throws an error - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: maybe you'd be better off with UNION in that case

Answer (score 2):

add a column for table sequence

```
select employeename, 1 as my_order from employeetable where employeename like 'vik%'
union
select employeename, 2 from employeetable where employeename like '% vik%'
union
select employeename, 3 from EmployeeTable where employeename like '%vik%' and employeename not like 'vik%' and employeename not like '% vik%'
order by my_order asc, empleemployeename asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select employeename, a as _order from employeetable where employeename like 'vik%'
union
select employeename, b as _order from employeetable where employeename like '% vik%'
union
select employeename, c as _order from EmployeeTable where employeename like '%vik%' and employeename not like 'vik%' and employeename not like '% vik%'
order by my_order asc, empleemployeename asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 s,employeename from employeetable where employeename like 'vik%'
union
select 2 s, semployeename from employeetable where employeename like    '%vik%'
union
select 3 s,employeename from EmployeeTable where employeename like '%vik%' and employeename not like 'vik%' and employeename not like '% vik%'     
order by s;
```

your further sort order within your 3 tables is undefined and could turn out as anything if not specified